# How do I filter by a subdocument substring using $indexOfCP?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

How do I return records from my 'greetsthings' collection where the 'things' doesn't have a specific substring?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d24e6e5e8b6b11536a8519b"),
    "message" : "hello",
    "meta" : {
        "info" : "friendly score 923",
        "things" : "cat bat dragon",
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d24e6e5e8b6b11536a8519c"),
    "message" : "hello",
    "meta" : {
        "info" : "confused score 622",
        "things" : "cat monkey dragon",
    }
}
```

I'm trying to query/filter for all 'hello message' records of `{$match:{ message: { $eq: 'hello' }}}` by a substring in `meta.things`

And by comparing the substring of *monkey* to *meta.things* to filter the results

When I try this **$filter** it errors with `"errmsg" : "input to $filter must be an array not object"`

```
db.getCollection('greetsthings').aggregate( 
[{$match:{ message: { $eq: 'hello' }}},
 {$project: {
    message: 1,
    "meta": {
       $filter: {$gte : [{$indexOfCP: ["$meta.things", "monkey"]},0]}
          }
       } 
    }
])
```

How can I return only records where the message is *hello* and *monkey* is in the `meta.things` string?

Comment: You are using `$filter` wrongly. It only filters nested arrays, not documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have "syntax" error with `"$meta.things"`. [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) allows compute operation with document's fields:

```
db.greetsthings.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$message",
              "hello"
            ]
          },
          {
            $gt: [
              {
                $indexOfCP: [
                  "$meta.things",
                  "monkey"
                ]
              },
              -1
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0AlveZ2TQXc)

*And also negation, how can I return records where the message is hello but dragon isn't in the meta.things string?*

> Searches a string for an occurence of a substring and returns the UTF-8 code point index (zero-based) of the first occurence. If the substring is not found, returns **-1**.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfCP/

```
$eq: [
  {
    $indexOfCP: [
      "$meta.things",
      "dragon"
    ]
  },
   -1
]
```

Comment: Thanks that helps.  In the result set I was hoping for the unmatched match records to be filtered out...  and I'm having trouble using $filter is that simple to add ?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

```
db.getCollection('greetsthings').aggregate(
    [{ $match: { message: 'hello' } },
    {
        $addFields: {
            shouldExists: { $gte: [{ $indexOfCP: ['$meta.things', "monkey"] }, 0] }, // Adds try if word monkey exists in string
            shouldNotExists: { $gte: [{ $indexOfCP: ['$meta.things', "dragon"] }, 0] } // Adds try if word dragon exists in string
        }
    }, { $match: { shouldExists: true, shouldNotExists: false } },
    { $project: { shouldExists: 0, shouldNotExists: 0 } }
    ])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/l2qy5ubkU0F)